# setuptools generated project command works fine but pip install tar package gives error module not found

Tags: python, setuptools

python3.7, centos7.2 and pip 18.
The project has following structure. When I run `pip install -e .` and then `proxy-tools` works fine.

However, when I run `python setup.py sdist` and run `pip install proxy-tools-1.0.0.tar.gz`, then `proxy-tools` gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tiina/proxy-tools-runtime/venv/bin/proxy-tools", line 6, in <module>
    from proxy_tools.agent.http_server2 import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proxy_tools'
```

folder structure:

```
.
|-- dist
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- proxy_tools
|-- proxy_tools.egg-info
|-- setup.py
`-- venv
```

and in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='proxy_tools',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'alabaster',
    ],
    entry_points="""
         [console_scripts]
         proxy-tools = proxy_tools.agent.http_server2:main
    """,
)
```

Because it is python3.7, so every module is imported from `proxy_tools`

Comment: I found the reason. a proxy_tools/__init__.py is missing. But why this does not cause problem for `pip install -e .` is not known.

Comment: `setuptools.find_packages()` will not collect `proxy_tools` if it doesn't contain an `__init__.py`. When you build a dist file, it will not contain code under `proxy_tools`. You can test it yourself by running `python -c "from setuptools import find_packages; print(find_packages())"`. `pip install --editable` works because it simply creates a link to the project dir where `proxy_tools` exists and contains the code. Python treats it as a namespace package and imports stuff just fine.